# is there a way to pass rendered variables from pug templates to client side JS files?

Tags: node.js, express, chart.js, pug

I am making a small project with Node.js, Express and Pug templates. I am passing data with res.render('template', {processedData}); to pug template where I have two graphs created with Chart.js. I need to pass some data from processedData variable to client side JS files in order to configure Chart.js graphs or find a workaround to achieve what I want.

So far I have tried to write configuration for graphs in plain JS code since you can do that by writing '- ' before your code or using 'script.' tag, but so far these methods do not seem to work. :|

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to convert your object with [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
script.
    var processedData = !{JSON.stringify(processedData)}
```

Or `window.processedData = !{JSON.stringify(processedData)}`, which gives you global access.